# Is there a way to update the Internet Explorer in SQL Server Management Studio 2012?

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012

Strangely, it seems MS SMS 2012 has its own IE which is separate from the one on my Windows 7 machine.  I've got IE11 installed on my machine, but inside of SMS2012 on the same machine, if I launch the browser (Ctrl-Alt-R) from SMS, it's IE7.  I confirmed this by going to http://www.whatbrowser.org/.

A number of websites tell me I'm using an old/unsupported browser and that I should upgrade.  But when I try to do so, it updates my PC instance, not the SMS instance.

I checked on a colleague's machine, and his IE inside of SMS 2012 is higher (9 or 10?).

I've tried installing SP2, and I'm currently falling short of uninstalling SMS and re-installing it since this might be more disruptive than its worth.

Any ideas how to upgrade the browser used in SMS, or re-direct it to launch the IE installed on the machine?

"Why in the world wouldn't you just fire up your favourite browser outside of SMS you ask?"  Actually, some of my query results contain XML links, which can then be used to spawn a web URL.  It would be very convenient to just click my way to the URL, instead of having to copy it and paste into a browser elsewhere.

Comment: Strange never noticed that. In SQL 2014 still appear as version IE7. Probably this was embedded to be used for displaying MSDN pages and not for other purposes.